# Enabling intellitrace for assemblies loaded at runtime?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, intellitrace

I have a self hosted WCF service that receives instructions and loads the appropriate assembly to perform work.  I would like to debug a running instance with Intellitrace, but when I attach Visual Studio (with the assembly's project open to the running process) the intellitrace pane remains blank.  I am attaching with Native and Managed v4.0, 4.5.  I have symbols loaded and can breakpoint and view property information.  Intellitrace just doesn't seem to want to monitor the process.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So I am not entirely sure what you are asking exactly but it sounds like you are using reflection to load an assembly into a running service.  If this is the case then intellitrace doesn't work because the assembly is loaded during execution, this is why you can see the properties but intellitrace doesn't work

Comment: I am indeed loading assemblies during execution using Assembly.LoadFrom().  I figured that intellitrace would be intelligent enough to monitor the goings on in the assembly, but I suppose not.  I was asking how to configure intellitrace to pick up events and call information in the loaded assembly.  If it wont do this, then I may not bother buying Ultimate (currently in the trail period).

Comment: yeah i don't think it's possible since the assembly doesn't actually get loaded until runtime, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliTrace do not support attaching to a already running process, you need to launch the process either from Visual Studio or from command line with IntelliTrace to monitor it. Also mix mode debugging (debug both Native and Managed code) isn't supported by IntelliTrace.

Note that assemblies loaded by Assembly.LoadFrom() will still be monitored by IntelliTrace so long as IntelliTrace is properly enabled on the loader process. In you case IntelliTrace will decide not to monitor anything.